# Should the word "component" be singular or plural in the name for PCA?

Tags: pca, terminology

I'm wondering which of the namings is right: Principal component**s** analysis or principal component analysis.

When I googled "principal component analysis" I got 526,000,000 related results, whereas when I googled "principal component**s** analysis" I got 482,000,000. So the former outnumbers the latter on Google, and indeed when I typed "principal component**s** analysis" google only showed the websites that contain "principal component analysis" in its title, including Wikipedia.

However, PCA is written as "principal component**s** analysis" in the famous "Deep Learning" book by Ian Goodfellow, and as far as I know "principal component**s** analysis" is more widely used in biological literatures.

Although I always assume no algorithmic differences whichever people use, I want to make it clear which one is more preferably used and why.

Comment: I put the **s** in bold as it took me a while to notice the difference between the two expressions.

Comment: The downvotes here aren't explained but can be imputed as implying (1) this is trivial (2) this is off-topic as a matter of (English) usage. Against those imputed arguments I would reply (1) it's a small point, but deserves its moment (2) I wouldn't want to delegate or relegate this discussion to another SE site where people knowing almost nothing about statistics predominate. There are many people here well-informed about language as well as statistics.

Comment: Note that the number of results reported by Google is close to meaningless, since it depends heavily on your personal [search engine bubble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_bubble). For instance, I get 413 million results for "principal component analysis" and 472 million results for "principal component**s** analysis" (both without the quotes), so for me, the pattern is reversed!

Comment: @StephanKolassa: the easy way to avoid the effect of personalized search engine bubble is to repeat the search when logged out, and ideally from other geos/IPs, and in general with language preferences set to a wide set of languages.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ian Jolliffe discusses this on p.viii of the 2002 second edition of his *Principal Component Analysis* (New York: Springer) -- which, as you can see immediately, jumps one way. He expresses a definite preference for that form *principal component analysis* as similar to say *factor analysis*  or *cluster analysis* and cites evidence that it is more common any way. Fortuitously, but fortunately for this question, this material is visible on my local Amazon site, and perhaps on yours too.

I add that the form *independent component analysis* seems overwhelmingly preponderant for that approach, although whether this is, as it were, independent evidence might be in doubt.

It's not  evident from the title but J.E. Jackson's *A User's Guide to Principal Components* (New York: John Wiley, 1991) has the same choice.

A grab sample of multivariate books from my shelves suggests a majority for the singular form.

An argument I would respect might be that in most cases the point is to calculate several principal components, but a similar point could be made for several factors or several clusters. I suggest that the variants *factors analysis* and *clusters analysis*, which I can't recall ever seeing in print, would typically be regarded as non-standard or typos by reviewers, copy-editors or editors.

I can't see that *principal components analysis* is wrong in any sense, statistically or linguistically, and it is certainly often seen, but I would suggest following leading authorities and using *principal component analysis* unless you have arguments to the contrary or consider your own taste paramount.

I write as a native (British) English speaker and have no idea on whether there are arguments the other way in any other language -- perhaps through grammatical rules, as the mathematics and statistics of PCA are universal. I hope for comments in that direction.

If in doubt, define PCA once and refer to that thereafter, and hope that anyone passionate for the form you don't use doesn't notice. Or write about empirical orthogonal functions.

Comment: All the cool kids are doing EOF these days, 'PCA' is *so 2019*...

Answer (score 10):

[NGrams from Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=principal%20components%20analysis%2Cprincipal%20component%20analysis&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprincipal%20components%20analysis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprincipal%20component%20analysis%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cprincipal%20components%20analysis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprincipal%20component%20analysis%3B%2Cc0) suggests they were similar in frequency of use from 1960 to about 1982, after which the *without-s* form started to be more popular.

This suggests to me that neither form is wrong but the *without-s* form may be slightly more comfortable to say.
[image]

Answer (score 10):

- When Hotelling first used the words 'analysis', 'component(s)' and 'principal' together. It was in the plural form.

  But it wasn't exactly as PCA yet and it was 'method of principal components' or in the title ['Analysis of a complex of statistical variables into principal components.'](https://psycnet.apa.org/doi/10.1037/h0071325)
- In most other languages the plural form is used. For instance, in French it is 'Analyse en composantes principales' and in German it is 'Hauptkomponentenanalyse'.

However, in the English language the singular form is more common.

The reason for the singular form is because this is the common way in English language. See for the canonical question on the English forum:

[When are attributive nouns plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/when-are-attributive-nouns-plural).

And there are many other related question asking for instance for '[number(s) analysis](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229525)'.

Comment: (+1) Helpful details. FWIW, Hotelling gave the name but Karl Pearson is often given credit for the basic idea. I think I've seen ACP in French language literature. Is there an abbreviation e.g. HKA in German language literature?

Comment: @NickCox I am not sure about German literature, but in Dutch it is often just called PCA.

Comment: Actually I am not sure about my last comment. English is the language used at Dutch universities nowadays, and maybe I am not old enough that I had to learn about the Dutch word on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 5):

I learned it as "principal components analysis" and I find some others insisting that the singular is better.

You buy books at a "book store", not at a "books store", and you won't touch something with a ten-foot pole, not a ten-feet pole, etc. That is a trait of the English language. In German it's exactly the other way around: the plural is used for things like this. So "principal component analysis" follows the pattern usually followed in English.

Comment: "cattle market" is an exception to the rule, although,perhaps because "bull market" means something different and "cow market" would not be a good word for anywhere where bulls or bullocks were also sold. Still, my guess is that exceptions are rare. The bigger question is why _principal components analysis_ is so common if it's malformed.

Comment: @NickCox : The singular of "cattle" seems to be "head of cattle".

Comment: Indeed, but whoever says or writes "a head of cattle" or "one head of cattle". It's a singular only by virtue of multiplication by a number making it a plural. (Just extending your comment, not disagreeing with it.)

Comment: Historically "cattle" meant any domesticated animal farmed for its meat. In other words it was a collective noun, not the plural of "cow or bull". (Similarly "corn" in British English is still a collective noun for any type of cereal grain, not just a synonym for "maize" as it is in American English).

Comment: @Nick Cox: I recall reading in some pop. sci. book that whether nouns in attributive position were pluralized or not was a matter of some interest to linguists. It would appear that there's a strong tendency for the uninflected noun to be the standard; so that someone who sells cockles is a cockle seller, though he'd hardly make a living selling a single cockle. When the plural's irregular, or when the sense of the singular noun's a little different, the plural tends to be the standard - so we don't see *datum scientists*, or *arm dealers*, or *purple person eaters*, or indeed *cow markets*.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica : But you wouldn't say "cows markets". (Besides, not all cattle are female.)

Comment: I agree - I don't understand the 'but' & 'besides'.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica : The plural of "cow" is "cows". But not all cattle are cows, i.e. not all are female.

Comment: Precisely - we don't have a good singular for *cattle*, so we're pretty much forced to make an exception to the rule here.

Comment: @Scortchi and friends: Interestingly digressive digressions, and indeed I started it. I'd assert that in contemporary (British) English, cattle only connotes bovine species, so that e.g sheep, goats, llamas no longer qualify. It's quite true that much wider usages can be found historically, which I didn't know. "Livestock" seems to be the wider referent. Whether livestock includes say poultry, I wouldn't know.  A paltry matter.

Comment: @NickCox : I've never heard of "cattle" denoting anything non-bovine. Why do you bring that up?

Comment: @alephzero already made the point that the word had a wider meaning.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rely on google search as a "majority vote" criterion, I think you should put quotes around the three words. This what I get:

- "Principal component analysis": 12,400,000 results
- "Principal component**S** analysis": 2,880,000 results

Wikipedia's article is also without S.